# Flash2Cocos2d port for Cocos2dx

Tags: cocos2d-x

An IOS game that i am porting to Cocos2dx has used a Flash2Cocs2d library for porting Skeltal Animations. Is there any Cocos2dx port that provides me the same support. I found [this](https://github.com/2youyouo2/Flash2Cocos2d-x) library, but cannot tell if it is the same as the library used for Cocos2d. The original library is [here](https://github.com/TheDamArmada).

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution for this. It's called [GAF](http://gafmedia.com/) This is set of runtimes and a convertor that can playback flash animations on the set of platforms including cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x and unity. Plugin for cocos2d-x is [here](https://github.com/CatalystApps/Cocos2dxGAFPlayer) and here is [converter](http://gafmedia.com/downloads)